# Path variable not being set with new values

Tags: unix

I have the following at the end of my script:

```
export PATH=/usr/openwin/bin:/opt/plat/AUTOSYS/4.0/autosys/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin::/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/opt/netezzaClient/bin:/xenv/ant/X/1.8.0/bin:/export/opt/jdk/1.6.0_16/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/export/opt/jdk/1.6.0_16
echo "END PATH - $PATH"
```

which prints this.

```
END PATH - /usr/openwin/bin:/opt/plat/AUTOSYS/4.0/autosys/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin::/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/opt/netezzaClient/bin:/xenv/ant/X/1.8.0/bin:/export/opt/jdk/1.6.0_16/bin:/opt/edtsesn/share/bin:/xenv/cvs/sun4/5.6p4/1.10/bin:/xenv/rationalrose/sun4/5.x/6.0.9242/rose/bin:/opt/netscape/4.70_B2/bin:/opt/SCssh/3.4_C0/bin:/opt/PDolvwm/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin:/usr/local/etc:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/etc:/software/scripts:/usr/5bin:/usr/demo:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/tran/sparc/lib:/usr/ccs/bin:/opt/sybase/1192/bin:/tmp/wm40824:/opt/edtsdba/bin:/xenv/scripts/bin:/xenv/workshop/sun4/5.8mu4/6.1a/bin:/home/pj03962/1192/bin:/home/pj03962/1192/bin:/xenv/java/X/1.6.0_11/bin:/xenv/cvs/:/xenv/java/X/1.6.0_11/bin:/xenv/cvs/sun4/5.6p4/1.10/bin:/xenv/ant/sun4/5.x/1.6.2/bin:/opt/SCssh/3.7.1_C0/bin:/opt/xemacs/bin:/home/pj03962/125/OCS-12_5/bin:/home/pj03962/125/125/bin:/opt/perforce/bin:/opt/netezzaClient/bin:/opt/netezzaClient/bin
```

yet

```
bash-3.00$ env $PATH
env: /usr/kerberos/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin: No such file or directory
```

No such file comes because a /home/usr/ folder does not exist for my account. But this still does not shed any light as to why it has not added the other values to the path variable.

Comment: What did you expect `env $PATH` to do?

Comment: Show me the lists of values set to $PATH, which should now include those in the print statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you've called your script without sourcing it.
For example, if your script is named "myscript.sh", you may have called "./myscript.sh" or "bash myscript.sh". Your modifications of env var inside the script won't leak out the script, you need to source it (call it with 'source' or '.' first).
eg:

```
. ./myscript.sh
```

The changes in myscript.sh will modify your current environment.

For the "env $PATH" : I think it's an error, since you're trying to run the command in the "PATH" variable. Which doesn't exist (/usr/kerberos/bin:/bin:... isn't the name of an existing file on your system !).
You should use instead: echo $PATH